# Nvidia drivers and external connections via HDMI not working when using a dual card laptop, but works with Intel card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, intel-graphics, gpu-driver, nvidia-prime

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.04 (coming from Linux mint 17 for gnome shell). Everything works fine with the exception of my second monitor, attached to my laptop via HDMI. I installed the proprietary drivers (and nvidia prime). Switching from intel to nvidia and back again works very well. However when using nvidia the HDMI port seems to not want to play nice. I plug in the cable and the main screen (on the laptop) and the external monitor flash on and off (or black and off). When using the intel card the external monitor works fine.

In Mint, I was using nvidia-prime and prime-indicator to make the enter setup run on one card or another. This is the setup I would like to use. I would like to run. I want to run the entire Xorg server using either Nvidia or Intel switch as I see fit. Using `prime-select nvidia` or `prime-select Intel` has always worked very well for me in the past. I generally run Nvidia and switch to Intel when traveling for better battery life.

What I have done is

- set the video driver for the Intel card to "modesetting" - X would not start at all
- Downgraded the Nvidia drivers - No change
- Disabled gpu-manager - No change or X wouldn't start (as expected)
- Used the open source drivers for nvidia  - Work as expected but performance is horrid and there are other massive issues that prevent this from working well.
- Disable Kernal Mode Setting - Xorg would not load

I am not sure what to try next. It worked just fine in Linux Mint, so I know it *should* work, but I compared configs to those I had in the pre-install backup and every thing looks the same, except kernel version and driver version, those are newer in Ubuntu.

lspci (important parts)

```
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 745M] (rev ff)  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

xorg log has nothing of value except maybe: (last line repeats a lot)

```
[    82.779] have a master to look out for  
[    82.820] need to create shared pixmap 1reporting 4 5 24 192  
[    82.861] reporting 4 5 24 192  
[    82.862] reporting 4 5 24 192  
[    82.862] reporting 4 5 24 192  
[    82.863] reporting 4 5 24 192  
[    82.864] reporting 4 5 24 192  
[    82.864] reporting 4 5 24 192  
[    82.864] reporting 4 5 24 192  
[    82.865] reporting 4 5 24 192  
[    82.865] reporting 4 5 24 192  
[    82.865] reporting 4 5 24 192  
[    82.866] reporting 4 5 24 192  
[    82.866] reporting 4 5 24 192
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bumblebee instead of nvidia-prime for switching GPUs.

In this case DE will use Intel and HDMI will work.

You will be able to start specific applications using NVIDIA GPU with optirun command. Or add this command to .desktop shortcuts.

Comment: I do not wish to use Bumblebee. I wish to use nvidia prime. Bumblebee does not seem to work well on this laptop. Even if it did, it would still not be the best option to me. Thanks though

Comment: Exacly the same problem, by chance I found the HDMI port and external display to be working if I plug it AFTER reboot. YMMV.